# When I change the variable name in a lambda function, the result changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I defined some lambdas and attempt to execute them. These are the lambda functions I have defined.

```
a = []
for i in range(3):
    a.append(lambda a:i+a)
```

When I execute the following code :

```
for j in range(3):
    print(a[j](0))
```

The results are:

```
2
2
2
```

But when I change the variable name and do the same thing:

```
for i in range(3):
    print(a[i](0))
```

I can not get the same results:

```
0
1
2
```

I don't understand why this is happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not saving the variable's value inside the lambda. You're saving a variable defined outside of the lambda. It's not necessarily a global variable, but to the scope of the lambda, it is declared outside of it. When the iteration terminates, the value of `i` is 2. That's why when you iterate with for-loop using `j`, the value inside the lambda is always `2`.

When you iterate on a for-loop using the `i` variable, you're once again changing the state of `i` before executing the lambda. That's why it gives you a different result.

To make the lambda get the variable's value only without keeping it dependant of any variable scope, do something like this:

```
a = []
for i in range(3):
    a.append((lambda k: lambda x:(k+x))(i))
```

`lambda k: ...` is used to pass the state of `i` to the inner lambda. It's in fact executing the function, and returning `lambda x: (k+x)`, where `k` is a private variable from the lambda's scope.

Now when you try to print it using another variable, such as `j`, or assigning a new value to `i` or `k`:

```
i = 256
k = 512

for j in range(3):
    print(a[j](0))
```

The output is:

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: A more idiomatic solution to binding a variable value to the scope of a lambda function is to pass it as the default value of a parameter. See the duplicate link for details.

Comment: I didn't know it could be done that way. Good to know, thanks.